# Trying to hide SHDocVw.InternetExplorer instance fails

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, shdocvw.internetexplorer

I have a grid with a button to launch an IE instance with some params and I would like to keep this instance so I can hide the IE window when the user navigates to another row. All the navigating etc.. works fine.  I have a class used as a singleton with an instance var for the SHDocVw.InternetExplorer object.

I can launch and show the URL but when the I try to set Visible = false - the IE window does not hide.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be if Navigate or Navigate2 fails (meaning you got a 404 or similar) it seems to think that's an internal exception. Once I had a valid URL it worked.